# Equivalent $request->path() in pure php

Tags: php, laravel, url

Assume this url:

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/add/11
```

The result of this code: `echo $request->path()` is `add/11`. Now I want to know how can I get that value in pure php?

---

Because I need to use that value in a view which isn't called by a controller *(it is a master view)*.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin It is a Blade view. It is `layouts/app.blade.php` *(which is a default view in laravel)*

Comment: Did you tried accessing request helper? `{{ request()->path() }}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using **blade**, try this:

```
{{ request()->path() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a Blade view, you can use Request facade:

```
Request::path()
```

Or global helper:

```
request()->path();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path_only = parse_url('http://localhost/myproject/public/add/11', PHP_URL_PATH)
echo $path_only;
```

and result :

> /myproject/public/add/11